# Showing virtual attributes that doesn't exist in the database in the view template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Am trying to show on the view template information not in the database but deduced out of logic, but it doesn't work for me.

Here is what I have done:

**models**

```
class SignupHistory < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor(:device)

  def device_used # This method returns the device used from User-Agent and mapped as either Desktop or Mobile
    device = "#{request.headers["User-Agent"].match(/\(.*?\)/)[0].split('(')[1].split(';')[0]}"
    [:Macintosh, :Windows, :Linux, :Unix].include?(device) ? 'Desktop' : 'Mobile'
  end
end
```

**template view**

```
.row
  .panel.panel-primary
    .panel-heading
      span = t('admin_header.traffics')
    .panel-body
      = table_for(@traffic, class: 'table table-condensed table-hover') do |t|
        - t.column :device, 'Devise Used', class: 'col-xs-2' # I want to output the returned value in device_used method here.
```

I dont want to create a new attribute in the database, I just wanna show that object in the view for all entries in the database.

As you can see from the image below and it should show the result of device_used method, but doesn't show anything
[image: template view picture]

Comment: Try changing `device_used` to `device`

Answer (score 0):

```
class SignupHistory < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor(:device)

  def device_used # This method returns the device used from User-Agent and mapped as either Desktop or Mobile
    device = "#{request.headers["User-Agent"].match(/\(.*?\)/)[0].split('(')[1].split(';')[0]}"
    [:Macintosh, :Windows, :Linux, :Unix].include?(device) ? 'Desktop' : 'Mobile'
  end
```

the `device` in your `device_used` method is a local variable, which is not accessible the way you are wanting, attr_accessor in this case is the same as writing this, which is why your column is blank

```
def device
end
```

To accomplish what you want, you want to use an alias, you should add this to your class and will be good to go.

`alias_method :device, :device_used`

Comment: Still didn't work, are you saying I should use instance variable instead or a local variable?

Comment: Did you do the alias after it was defined or before?  alias_method should be after the `device_used` is defined for the class to define it properly

Comment: Thats what I have done, but it doesnt work. What goes to my template view maybe thats where the problem is?

Comment: Hmmm, so going back to assumptions then, what is the `@traffic` is it an instance of a SignupHistory?

Comment: It is an instance variable to show method logic, which shouldn't affect the solution I think

Comment: Ah so i think that is it, your traffic isn't something that responds to device.  What is that things class?  If it isn't a SignupHistory then you will have to wire up the @traffic to be able to respond to device and delegate that call to the related SignupHistory